# How to set proxy in JProfiler on MacOS

Tags: jprofiler

I'm behind a corporate proxy. So this needs to configured in JProfiler to allow attaching to remote JVMs and checking for updates. However going through the menu I cannot the corresponding settings.
How do I configure a proxy within JProfiler.

I'd expect JProfiler to use the system's proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: To use the OS's proxy add property `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` to `~/.jprofiler13/jprofiler.vmoptions`